# .htaccess error redirecting to another directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problem with .htaccess that rewrite my url. I created a simple dynamic website and I cant figure how to fix it. This is my login url localhost/foss/ then after successful login the user will be redirected to localhost/foss/main

here is the code of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

and here is my php that handle include files depending on the p value.

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['p'];
    $pages = array('home', 'inv_view', 'inv_add', 'inv_delete', 'inv_edit', 's_view', 's_add', 's_delete', 'change_pass', 'register', 'logout');
    if (!empty($page))
    {
        if(in_array($page, $pages))
            include $page . '.php';
        else
            echo 'Page not found!';
    }
    else
        include 'home.php';         
?>
```

this is working fine, the only weird things that going on, is after the user is redirected to the localhost/foss/main, the .htaccess rewrite the url to localhost/foss/main/?p=main, but when i choose a link like localhost/foss/main/home it will work normally. how can i get rid of the ?p=main after the user login and redirected to localhost/foss/main

Comment: Where is redirection to `localhost/foss/main` happening?

Comment: it was after the user successfully login, localhost/foss/login.php

and here is the code header('refresh: 5; url = main');

Comment: @anubhava lol. that was easy. i got a little confuse with htaccess. main is a directory, that's why i needs / at the end. am i right? btw thanks.

Comment: Have posted a detailed answer below for the reason of this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why this behavior is happening because `mod_dir` module is running after `mod_rewrite` and adding a trailing slash in front of directory `main/` after your rewrite rule and you get final URL as `localhost/foss/main/?p=main`.

To fix this issue have a trailing slash in your refresh tag:

```
header('refresh: 5; url = main/');
```